# How to show heads up notification in Oreo or higher

Tags: android

I  think  heads up notification disable in android 8.0  but android's built-in message have this feature even on running android 8.0 .
I know how to show heads up notification lower than 8.0 device by setting vibration to notification. But vibration on notification running Oreo is deprecated. So i go and search in internet and someone says enabling setVibrationPattern to notification channel  will works. But saddly this not works .

So here is my code .

```
Notification  builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
                            .setChannelId(id)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                            .setColor(setActionColor(counter))
                            .setColorized(true)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .build();

//Notification channel code.

NotificationChannel chan2 = new NotificationChannel(SECONDARY_CHANNEL,
                            getString(R.string.noti_channel_second), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                    chan2.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
                    chan2.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                    manager.createNotificationChannel(chan2);
                    manager.notify(notificationID, builder);
```

Comment: have u tried notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

Comment: Yes. But saddly not worked.

Comment: You might need to create Notification Chanel inorder to support headsup notifications on Android 8

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall your app? I have a similar code structure and is able to get the heads-up notifications. I figured that if you didn't set the priority correctly (should be both `NotificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH` and NotificationChannel as `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH`) during the first time you compile your app, even though you corrected it in the code and recompile the app, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 27):

**Late Answer** :- But i think its worth sharing.
 I was doing the same thing as above but `Heads-up notifications` won't shows in Oreo.

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = 
        new NotificationChannel("ch_nr", "CHART", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{300, 300, 300});

    if (defaultSoundUri != null) {
        AudioAttributes att = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        notificationChannel.setSound(defaultSoundUri, att);
    }

    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    notificationBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, notificationChannel.getId());
}
```

Essential code is above . 
The problem was i was overriding build each time on device and the `importance` did not get change to HIGH . I did not understand  this until i came across this [document](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-notifications.html#settings) .

> **Importance levels have the following restrictions:**
>
> The importance level you assign will be the channel’s default. Users can change a channel’s importance level in Android Settings.
>   Once you choose an importance level, you're limited in how you can change it: you may only lower the importance, and only if the user hasn't explicitly changed it.

**Conclusion**:- Completely uninstall previous build or Clear Data(not sure about this) before upgrading the importance for notification channel.

Comment: Uninstall always a good idea when making notification code changes. Thanks for forcing me to not be so lazy, worked for me.

Comment: Very helpful.  My code did not work until I did the uninstall.  Thanks much.

Comment: Thanks!! I though I get crazy, but you help me

Comment: Thanks! You save me :) I did uninstall my app and run again. It works!

Answer (score 13):

You can do this way.. this will work on every android version

```
private NotificationManager notifManager;
public void createNotification(String aMessage) {
    final int NOTIFY_ID = 1002;

    // There are hardcoding only for show it's just strings
    String name = "my_package_channel";
    String id = "my_package_channel_1"; // The user-visible name of the channel.
    String description = "my_package_first_channel"; // The user-visible description of the channel.

    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    if (notifManager == null) {
        notifManager =
                (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
        if (mChannel == null) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(description);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);

        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        builder.setContentTitle(aMessage)  // required
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder) // required
                .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker(aMessage)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    } else {

        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        builder.setContentTitle(aMessage)                           // required
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder) // required
                .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.app_name))  // required
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker(aMessage)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    } // else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notifManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: Where ever you are right now, I just want you to know, thank you for this! Notifications in Oreo has gotten so complicated compared to the old APIs. I needed a cookbook example and this really nails it.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to set the App notification setting in "Settings" to Urgent.  A Heads up notification will not show up unless the User sets the App to urgent.

Comment: thanks for answer i solved this issue myself . the problem is rom not allowed it to heads up on all application except built-in message app.

Comment: @Rk215Tech can I get the reference where you saw the argument that the heads-up is only enabled for the built-in message apps? I found apps like FB Messenger and Venmo can show heads-up on Android 8.0, too.

Answer (score 2):

Heads up notifications works if you create Notification Channel and do something like this.

```
NotificationChannel chan2 = new NotificationChannel(SECONDARY_CHANNEL,
                getString(R.string.noti_channel_second), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        chan2.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan2.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        getManager().createNotificationChannel(chan2);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are setting the wrong channel ID.**

> setChannelId(String channelId) specifies the channel the notification
>   should be delivered on.

And here in your example you are setting some `id` to your notification builder:
`setChannelId(id)`
and then creating a new secondary channel that you are not specifying: `chan2`

---

Here is my working example:

```
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_NO_1";

    public void sendNotification(Context context) {

       // Create your notification channel 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            CharSequence name = "New riddle";
            String description = "Riddle of the day";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            // IMPORTANT: CHANNEL_ID
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);


            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }


        // Get an instance of NotificationManager
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setContentTitle("Riddle of the day:")

                //IMPORTANT: CHANNEL_ID
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)

        // It won't show "Heads Up" unless it plays a sound     
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);


        // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service//
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

---

*One more thing, make sure to **REINSTALL** your app after making these changes.*

Answer (score 0):

In some phones, there is a status bar and notification setting where if the top preview of notification is set to **no preview**, then it won't allow any app to show heads up, setting it to **banner** will solve your problem if you have already set up your channel and notification properly.

I faced the same issue with the Android 9 OS, Vivo y1902 phone, which was resolved after making the above changes.